# Running GDAL sieve in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal

I'm getting this error when trying to run the GDAL sieve plugin in the latest version of QGIS:

> Either gdal_sieve.bat is missing, or you may have insufficient
> permissions to run the program

I have admin permissions.

Any ideas how to get this running in a windows environment?

Comment: How did you install QGIS?

Comment: I downloaded the latest stable windows release from the QGIS website and ran the windows installer package

Comment: It works for me but I have used the generic OSGeo4W installer. Can you find the gdal_sieve.bat file from your file system?

Comment: no, I haven't been able to find that file. I'll give the OSGeo4W installer a try. I can see other tools missing too (e.g. georeferencer)

Comment: nope, still no luck, but I have found the gdal_sieve.bat file in C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.34.5\apps\Python39\Scripts - any idea how to point QGIS in the right direction to find it?

Comment: If QGIS cannot find the script then there must be some issue with the paths. The OSGeo4W installer creates .bat files for launching the applications into the \bin directory under the installation directory and usually they set the paths correctly. The georeferencer is nowadays in the Layers menu, did you search it from there?

Comment: @user30184 - I have got it working by changing the environment settings to Append under Apply, Variable = Path and the folder location shown above in the Value section. Now I just need to find what happened to the Georeferencer tool!

Comment: Aha, thanks for the tip on the Georeferencer - found it where you mentioned!